# Cannot change month in datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Have this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#effectiveDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
                minDate: 1,
                maxDate: '+4Y',
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
                showOn: "both",
                buttonImage: "<%=whatIsContextPath%>/images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true
            });
        });
```

this is result:

[image]

How do I make sure I can chose another month, like here:

[image]

Comment: You get that control by default: https://jsfiddle.net/8b31qnpd/. If it's not appearing for you then you probably have some CSS which is interfering with jQueryUI

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, you had right direction, i found that I haven't imported css for jquery-ui.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, just forgot to include add link to jquery-ui in my page:

```
<link type="text/css" href="<%=whatIsContextPath%>/stylesheet/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```